# How can I use spaces in systemd command line arguments?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd unit with spaces in an argument

```
ExecStart=command --argument="text text"
```

It seems that systemd does not recognize the double or single quotes and it splits up the argument into two arguments. Any idea how I can prevent that? I am using systemd v218 within CoreOS.

Comment: Escape with backslash?

Comment: document reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly difficult to do, unfortunately. I stole this info from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/728951/systemd-giving-my-service-multiple-arguments). The only way to do it is to put your arguments in an environment file and then use them as variables as such (like in /etc/.progconfig):

```
ARG1=text
ARG2=text
```

Then import the environment file before running your command:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/.progconf
ExecStart = command $ARG1 $ARG2
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now using 
    `Environment='ARGUMENT=text text'` and 
   `ExecStart = command --argument=$ARGUMENT`

and that works!

Comment: Can you explain more briefly how have you achieved it?

Comment: Judging by the amount of upvotes, this may have worked at some point. But it does not work anymore, at least in RHEL 7 (which is fairly old at this point). The variables need to be passed with braces as shown in @Niki's answer.

Answer (score 18):

systemd only seems to recognize quotes which fully wrap arguments; i.e.

`ExecStart=command "--argument=text text"`

works but

`ExecStart=command --argument="text text"`

does not. I just ran into this issue and filed [#624](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/624) about it.

Comment: I just came across this problem and it costs me several hours to figure out

Comment: With **systemd-246** even wrapping the whole arguments with double quotes doesn't work. In my case the command is `/my/path/mycommand "--myargs"`. I had to fall back to the solution provided by @Niki that is use an environment variable.

Answer (score 6):

As Nico suggested, you can create an EvironmentFile in which you can specify an argument with spaces.

```
SPACEYARG="i love spaces"
```

In your unit file however, you'll need to wrap that argument in curly brackets in order for the spaces to be passed properly.

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/.progconf
ExecStart = command ${SPACEYARG}
```

Comment: @nico's solution did not work for me. Neither did using double quotes around the variable name. Braces do work though. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think recent versions of systemd have started accepting quotes in the middle of arguments, closer to what bash accepts. However, @Tgr's answer is still correct, and it's worth elaborating on. Quoting the entire argument, including the flag name, works here. If you do this:

```
ExecStart=command "--argument=text text"
```

Then systemd will understand `--argument=text text` as a single positional argument. You don't have to worry about any more splitting happening on that space. You can see the same behavior in bash:

```
$ echo "--silly-flag=spaces     are    preserved here"
--silly-flag=spaces     are    preserved here
```

Answer (score 3):

Environment is a way to do it.

You can also use `\s` as space, so ExecStart will be:

```
ExecStart=command --argument="text=\stext"
```

ref: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines

Answer (score 1):

Systemd service file supports this

```
Environment="TEST=one word"
Environment="TEST2=second word"

ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo start pre
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo start pre mandatory
ExecStart=/bin/echo started : ${TEST} $TEST2
ExecStartPost=-/bin/echo start post
ExecStartPost=/bin/echo start post mandatory
ExecStop=/bin/echo stop
ExecStopPost=-/bin/echo stop post
ExecStopPost=/bin/echo stop post mandatory
ExecReload=/bin/echo reload
```

log :

```
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30286]: start pre
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30288]: start pre mandatory
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30295]: started : one word second word
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30296]: start post
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30297]: start post mandatory
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30298]: stop
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30299]: stop post
Mar 09 21:39:47 gitlab-runner-1 echo[30300]: stop post mandatory
```

But you may actually want to set this if the app needs to read the whole string as 2 arguments, each argument between "" (not tested)

```
ExecStart=command "$ARG1" "$ARG2"
```

Answer (score -3):

Try escaping the space, like so:

```
ExecStart=command --argument="text\ text"
```

(The quotes may or may not be necessary.)