# How to escape a systemd Specifier to pass to the command in ExecStart

Tags: tcpdump, systemd

I've written the following systemd service `tcpdumpd.service` to kick off a persistent tcpdump recording.

```
[Unit]
Description=TCPDumpd
After=multi-user.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/tcpdump -pni eth0 -s65535 -G 3600 -w '/var/log/tcpdump/trace_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap' -z gzip
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

tcpdump allows strftime-placeholders like %H for hour, %M for minute and so on to allow you to create time stamped files.

However, systemd has special specifiers than can be used in it, like (%n, %N, %p, %i, %U, %u, %m, %H, %b, %v)  So any of the specifiers that overlap, like %m and %H pass through the information from systemd and don't allow the placeholder to be passed through to tcpdump to make the time stamp.

Does anyone know if there is a way to escape the specifiers in systemd so I can pass the %m and %H through to tcpdump?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've tried to escape special specifiers like `%%m`, `\%m` without luck.

But, if you need the work to be done, here is workaround:

Create file `tcpdumpd.environment` containing definition of TCPDUMP_FORMAT variable.

```
TCPDUMP_FORMAT=%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S
```

Modify `tcpdumpd.service`: add `EnvironmentFile=` option to it and replace format string with `${TCPDUMP_FORMAT}`.

```
[Unit]
Description=TCPDumpd
After=multi-user.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=tcpdumpd.environment
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/tcpdump -pni eth0 -s65535 -G 3600 -w '/var/log/tcpdump/trace_${TCPDUMP_FORMAT}.pcap' -z gzip
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This is the solution.  Found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881758/how-can-i-use-spaces-in-systemd-command-line-arguments?rq=1) that got me to your exact solution.  Thanks!

Comment: With `systemd` version 215 you can use `Environment="TCPDUMP_FORMAT=%%Y-%%m-%%d_%%H:%%M:%%S"` instead of an `EnvironmentFile`.

Answer (score 6):

> Does anyone know if there is a way to escape the specifiers in systemd so I can pass the %m and %H through to tcpdump?

Yes: `%%m` and `%%H`.

See [man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

> "%%" | Single percent sign | Use "%%" in place of "%" to specify a single percent sign.