# Systemd ExecStart with arguments

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd

I have process, that i run in this way :

```
sudo RADIODEV=/dev/spidev0.0 /opt/basicstation/build-rpi-std/bin/station -d -h /opt/basicstation/build-rpi-std/bin
```

I would like to lunch it on raspberry boot with systemctl like that :

```
[Unit]
Description=Basic station secure websocket
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart= RADIODEV=/dev/spidev0.0 /opt/basicstation/build-rpi-std/bin/station -d -h /opt/basicstation/build-rpi-std/bin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=basic_station.service
```

So i want to know how put the argument

RADIODEV=/dev/spidev0.0
-d
-h /opt/basicstation/build-rpi-std/bin

because wheni just put :

```
 ExecStart= RADIODEV=/dev/spidev0.0 /opt/basicstation/build-rpi-std/bin/station -d -h /opt/basicstation/build-rpi-std/bin
```

That's not work

I already check some issue like : 
[issue systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881758/how-can-i-use-spaces-in-systemd-command-line-arguments)

But i can't reproduce what they propose.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service) for how to set an environment variable.